# How to append the return values in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here i selected the matched records from Database after that i return in previous page, here i got all values but i don't know how to append this return values in this page i need like insteed of **ROOM 2,Room 3...** append value in **value.room_number** and **PG NAME HERE** append in **value.bg_id**

---

I got values like this

```
var res =jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         console.log(res);
```

> count:2 data:Array[2] 0:Object 1:Object
>
> booking_status:"1"
>
> id:"2"
>
> pg_id:"1"
>
> rent:"4000"
>
> room_number:"Room 2"
>
> room_sharing:"2"
>
> ---
>
> booking_status:"1"
>
> id:"3"
>
> pg_id:"1"
>
> rent:"4000"
>
> room_number:"Room 3"
>
> room_sharing:"2"

```js
index.php
<script>
function showDiv(toggle){
var sharing=$("#sharing").val();
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
   url: "pg_details.php",
      data: "sharing_id="+sharing,
   success: function(data) {
   var res =jQuery.parseJSON(data);
   console.log(res);

   if(res['return'] == 1){
      var htmlString=''; 
      $.each( res['data'], function( key, value ){
     htmlString ='<div id="toggle"><div class="container" style=" margin-bottom: 30px;"><div class="row"><h4 style="margin-left:15px;">'+value.pg_id+'</h4><div class="col-sm-10"><div class="btn-group" id="btnmar"><a href="register.php?id=2"><button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style=" width: 71px; ">'+value.room_number+'</button></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></div><div class="col-sm-2"><div class="panel-group"><div class="panel panel-primary"><div class="panel-heading"> Premium Facility</div><div class="panel-body" style=" padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-television" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:15px;"></i>T.V.</div><div class="panel-body" style=" padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-wifi" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:15px;"></i>Wifi</div><div class="panel-body" style=" padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-bed" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:15px;"></i>Bed</div><div class="panel-body" style=" padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:15px;"></i>Washing Machine</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>';
    
   });
   $(".view_room").prepend(htmlString);
   
  }
      }
   });
}
</script>

pg_details.php

<?php
include_once("admin/config.php");
include("functions.php");
//$pg_name=Getpg($_POST['pg_id']);
$sharing=$_POST['sharing_id'];//Getting Sharing Value

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE room_sharing='$sharing'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($count > 0){
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
 $data[]= $row;
 }
 $pg_type= array("return"=>1,"count" =>$count,"data" =>$data);
    echo $pg_type = json_encode($pg_type);
}else{
 $pg_type= array("return"=>0,"count" =>0,"data" =>"");
    echo $pg_type = json_encode($pg_type);
}
?>
```

```html
<div class="view_room"></div>
```

Comment: remove this condition `if(res['return'] == 1){`. No mean there and stooping the append code to work. Also @poonam is totally correct too

Comment: In `each()` use `htmlString += ''` instead of `htmlString =''` and after loop use `$(".view_room").append(htmlString);`
You can use `if(res)` instead of `if(res['return'] == 1)`

Comment: My DB like this pg_id=1.two sharing room 2 rooms available names like Room2 and Room 3 ,here value is returning correct but while displaying Room 2 and fecilities are displaying one row and room 3 and fecilities displaying another row for me don't want like this i need like room 2 room 3 fecilities are come same row how can do?

Comment: suppose pg_id is diffrent means that time i want to show 1st row like pg_id and room numbers and fecilities and 2nd row pg_id etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "pg_details.php",
  data: "sharing_id=" + sharing,
  success: function(data) {
    var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    $.each(res.data, function(key, value) {
     el = $('[data-id='+value.pg_id +']');
     if (el.length) {
         el.find('.btnmar').append(' <a href="register.php?id='+value.id +'">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style=" width: 71px; ">'+value.room_number+'</button>
          </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
      } else {
     var htmlString =  '<div id="toggle" data-id="'+value.pg_id +'">
 <div class="container" style=" margin-bottom: 30px;">
    <div class="row">
      <h4 style="margin-left:15px;">'+value.pg_id +'</h4>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="btn-group btnmar">
          <a href="register.php?id='+value.id +'">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style=" width: 71px; ">'+value.room_number+'</button>
          </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="panel-group">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading"> Premium Facility</div>
            <div class="panel-body" style=" padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-television" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:15px;"></i>T.V.</div>
            <div class="panel-body" style=" padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-wifi" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:15px;"></i>Wifi</div>
            <div class="panel-body" style=" padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-bed" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:15px;"></i>Bed</div>
            <div class="panel-body" style=" padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:15px;"></i>Washing Machine</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';
   $(".view_room").prepend(htmlString);}
    });


  }
});
```

php for pg_name:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $row['pg_name'] = Getpgname($row['pg_id']);
    $data[]= $row;
    }
```

or use a join query to return both the name and data

Comment: My DB like this pg_id=1.two sharing room 2 rooms available names like Room2 and Room 3 ,here value is returning correct but while displaying Room 2 and fecilities are displaying one row and room 3 and fecilities displaying another row for me don't want like this i need like room 2 room 3 fecilities are come same row how can do?

Comment: suppose pg_id is diffrent means that time i want to show 1st row like pg_id and room numbers and fecilities and 2nd row pg_id etc...

Comment: Actually insteed of pg_id i want to show pg_name,already written in functions.php and function name is Getpgname($id);how call cal this function

Comment: @ManiM how you normally call a php function

Comment: Js how call php function and how to pass the paramater in that function

Comment: @ManiM you need to alter you php results and output the altered results to the page

Comment: Yes i got it,but one more thing i have one table called rooms in that i have one column called status,for me suppose status is 1 means i want show this button in red 0 means i want show green(insteed id primary color)

Comment: do a if add/remove class based on data.return

Comment: post another question